# Filter before Group by or after with CTE

Tags: sql, db2, subquery, query-optimization

Say I have a query:

```
SELECT SUM(Data1), SUM(Data2), UserID 
FROM Table1
WHERE Data1 IN (1, 2, 3)
  AND USERID IN (SELECT USERID IN SOME SMALLISH Table of ~10000 Values)
GROUP BY UserID
```

What is the performance of this query like? Is it better to just wrap it in a CTE and filter the USERID out after the group by? Will it scan each row with the IN? Then it must be faster to first group by right?

edit: Added missing aggregation as mentioned by User @jarlh

Comment: This depends on the database, on the indexes and partitions on the table, and perhaps on other factors (depending on the database).

Comment: If you had to go with a default solution, which would you use? Which would be the factors that would sway you in one or the other direction?

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregation is performed? Simply do SELECT DISTINCT!

Comment: I am sorry that is my bad there actually is an aggregation it is SUM I will edit. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Trust the optimizer, write easy to read SQL!

Comment: It is a very large table and before I added the user requirement the query took like half an hour to complete for a slice of a couple days, it is running for 2 hours now so I unfortunately don't think the optimizer is doing its job properly. I am not a DB admin so I don't have to much influence on the table.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Have you checked the explain/execution plan?

Comment: I am using db2. I am coming from SQL Server and am pretty new to db2, I would have to check how I can see the execution plan with db2 using command line only.

Comment: The result highly depends on data. If you have billions in `table1` and your subquery filters out just 20000 rows it is hard to be faster to aggregate first and then filter. Do you have exactly this query or `table1` or `some small table` are some subqueries too? You should check execution plan anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be inclined to change the query to use `EXISTS` -- although I'm not sure if this makes a difference in DB2 (some databases have better optimizers than others):

```
SELECT SUM(Data1), SUM(Data2), UserID 
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE Data1 IN (1, 2, 3) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM smallish s
              WHERE t2.USERID = t1.USERID
             )
GROUP BY UserID;
```

Then, if I understand correctly, your question is whether this query might perform better:

```
SELECT SUM(Data1), SUM(Data2), UserID 
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE Data1 IN (1, 2, 3)          
GROUP BY UserID
HAVING EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM smallish s
              WHERE t2.USERID = t1.USERID
             );
```

First, you can test the two versions on your data and your system.  That is always the best way to validate performance questions.

Second, I would expect the `WHERE` version to be faster -- and much faster -- because the aggregation has many fewer rows to aggregate.

One exception is if the database can use an index for the aggregation.  I would expect the `IN` to preclude that possibility.  Another exception is if the `EXISTS`/`IN` clause is really, really expensive (say no indexes are involved), then running it only once per result row *might* be faster.  That said, this is balanced against the larger amount of data in the aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `exists`:

```
select data1, data2, userid
from table1 t1
where 
    data1 in (1, 2, 3)
    and exists (select 1 from some_smallish_table s where s.userid = t.userid)
group by data1, data2, userid
```

Then, you want to make sure that you have an index on `some_smallish_table(userid)`, so the subquery executes quickly.